# How to replace using regex match in UIPath

Tags: .net, regex, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I have a regex to filter data

[image]

#Matches Result

```
 Homeowner's Insurance Premium ( 12 mo.) toAmerican Family  $893.00
 Insura
 Mortgage Insurance Premium (     mo.)
 Prepaid Interest ($5.99 per day from 10/02/2020 to 10/01/2020) -$5.99
```

Using for each loop on the Matches activity above , I want to remove all dollars like $893.00 , $5.99 etc
using the ff. regex , but it does no work . any idea ? thanks.

```
(.*)\s\$\d[\d.]*([^\r\n]*)(?:\r?\n(?!\d+ )(.+))?
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(item,"(.*)\s\$\d[\d.]*([^\r\n]*)(?:\r?\n(?!\d+ )(.+))?" , "")
```

Comment: `Regex.Replace(item, @"(.*)\s\$\d[\d.]*([^\r\n]*)(?:\r?\n(?!\d+ )(.+))?" , "$1$2$3")` - you  forgot to use the replacement pattern and use the verbatim string literal.

Comment: However, you say you want to remove all dollar amounts? Like `Regex.Replace(item, @"\s*[+-]?\$\d*\.?\d+", "")`?

Comment: Yes, just match the dollar amount could also work `-?\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}(?!\S)`

Comment: How about If I want to remove only the dollars at the last line so if the input si Prepaid Interest ($5.99 per day from 10/02/2020 to 10/01/2020) -$5.99  the output is  Prepaid Interest ($5.99 per day from 10/02/2020 to 10/01/2020)

Comment: `Regex.Replace(item, @"\s*[+-]?\$\d*\.?\d+\s*$", "")`?

Comment: create an answer sir so i can vote you , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the dollar amount at the end of the string you can use

```
Regex.Replace(item, @"\s*[+-]?\$\d*\.?\d+\s*$", "")
```

Make sure you use a *verbatim string literal*, `@"..."`, in C# code (it is not needed in VB.NET though), to be able to use a single `\` as the regex escape char.

The pattern means

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[+-]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\d*` - 0 or more digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

See the [RegexStorm regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs*%5B%2B-%5D%3F%5C%24%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B%5Cs*%24&i=Homeowner%27s%20Insurance%20Premium%20%28%2012%20mo.%29%20toAmerican%20Family%20%20%24893.00%0D%0A%20Insura%0D%0A%20Mortgage%20Insurance%20Premium%20%28%20%20%20%20%20mo.%29%0D%0A%20Prepaid%20Interest%20%28%245.99%20per%20day%20from%2010%2F02%2F2020%20to%2010%2F01%2F2020%29%20-%245.99&r=) (click the *Context* tab at the bottom to see the replacement result).